# Javascript intellisense in VS2015 unit test project

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing my angular unit tests in a Unit Test project in VS2015 but I cant get intellisense for the javascript. I've tried adding a _references.js file but had no joy. Is this even possible in this project type? Or can you only have js intellisense in a webapplication?

Answer (score 0):

From this link [Javascript editor improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/06/10/javascript-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx)

***Whenever you reference the angular.js (or angular.min.js) library in your code, editor automatically provides IntelliSense, Go to Definition, and navigation bar support:***

So as long as you have these referenced in your test project it should work

Comment: What do you mean by go to Definition, and navigation bar support? I have the angular.js library and jasmine-core.js referenced in my js files in the test project but I'm not getting intellisense.

Comment: Sorry about the cryptic text. I cut and pasted it from the link. I haven't got VS2015 open in front of me at the moment, but you could try looking in Tools/Options/Debugging from the VS2015 IDE there might be something that you need to tick in there

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to VS2015 and had the same problem. It worked just fine under 2013.4. It appears that VS is not resolving the _references file when the project type is not a web based one (mine was also an angular unit test project that was setup as a regular app project type).

Quick fix that worked for me was to manually add _references to the intellisense list.

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> Intellisense -> References
```

Add `~/Scripts/_references.js` to the `Implicit (Web)` category

[image]

It then worked correctly. Alternatively I suppose you could create a new Web project and move all your code to it but that seems like way too much work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer katharsis, I've done as you suggested but I'm still not getting any intellisense in my unit tests. Which has really surprised me, its also rather frustrating after ranting about how good 2015 looked for frontend development to my team and then it can't even handle simple intellisense :(

Comment: If you are using jasmine (and you are going to hate this so hopefully someone else will post a real solution) - I had to include a version of 1.X jasmine in the _references that is ONLY used for intellisense. I use 2.X for the actual code. Have not investigated why - obviously 2.X is structured differently internally. There are only a few small syntax differences and they are fairly easy to remember - but still a huge hack. Does work in 2015 (I did have to do the same hack in 2013 though too).

Comment: Cheers ktharsis I'll give that a go. What bothers me is that I don't seem to be able to get any intellisense for my JavaScript at all. I've added all the files to the _references file but just not getting anything coming through even for my own angular files.